# Creating a rectangular Tikz node that fill the entire width

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a rectangular Tikz node which fill the entire width of the graphic. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sf \scriptsize,
    >=LaTeX,
    cell/.style={
        rectangle, 
        sharp corners=5mm, 
        draw,
        very thick,
        },
    ]

    \node[cell] (foo) {foo};
    \node[cell, right=of foo] (bar) {bar};
    \node[cell, right=of bar] (baz) {baz};

    \node[cell](input) at (0, -1){I want this all the way};

    \draw[->] (input) -- (foo);
    \draw[->] (input) -- (bar);
    \draw[->] (input) -- (baz);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like for the outer most edges of the lower rectangle to align with `foo` and `baz`. Also it would be nice of the arrows were completely vertical.

Comment: What is *graphic* to you? Please, show us some compilable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can measure distance from left side of `foo` node to right side of the `baz` node and draw rectangle  wit this minimal width:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
          > = LaTeX,
cell/.style = {rectangle, draw, very thick, outer sep=0pt,
               font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
                ]
\node[cell] (foo) {foo};
\node[cell, right=of foo] (bar) {bar};
\node[cell, right=of bar] (baz) {baz};
\path   let \p1 = ($(foo.west)-(baz.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node[cell, minimum width=\n1,
             below right=1cm and 0cm of foo.south west] (input) {I want this all the way};
\draw[->]   (input) edge (foo)
            (input) edge (bar)
            (input)  to  (baz);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:** if you like to have vertical arrows between `input` node and other nodes, that you need to draw arrows as follows:

```
\draw[->]   (input.north -| foo) edge (foo)
            (input.north -| bar) edge (bar)
            (input.north -| baz)  to  (baz);
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the arrows vertical?

Comment: yes it is. i will show this asap.

Answer (score 2):

You are already loading the `fit` library, here is how you may use it. (Big thanks to @Ignasi for the improvements!)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sf \scriptsize,
    >=LaTeX,
    cell/.style={
        rectangle, 
        sharp corners=5mm, 
        draw,
        very thick,
        },
    ]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=misc]
    \node[cell] (foo) {foo};
    \node[cell, right=of foo] (bar) {bar};
    \node[cell, right=of bar] (baz) {baz};
    \end{scope}
    \node[cell,fit=(foo) (baz),inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, below=of bar,
    label=center:I want this all the way](input){}; 

    \draw[->] (input) -- (foo);
    \draw[->] (input) -- (bar);
    \draw[->] (input) -- (baz);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sf \scriptsize,
    >=LaTeX,
    cell/.style={
        rectangle, 
        sharp corners=5mm, 
        draw,
        very thick,
        },
    ]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=misc]
    \node[cell] (foo) {foo};
    \node[cell, right=of foo] (bar) {bar};
    \node[cell, right=of bar] (baz) {baz};
    \end{scope}
    \node[below=5mm of misc] (aux)  {I want this all the way};
    \node[cell,fit=(aux.north-|misc.west)
    (aux.south-|misc.east),inner sep=0pt](input){};

    \draw[->] (input) -- (foo);
    \draw[->] (input) -- (bar);
    \draw[->] (input) -- (baz);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It took me also some time to understand that `fit` nodes can be placed in any position and not only surrounding the fitting coordinates. Therefore you could use `\node[cell,fit=(foo) (baz),inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, below=of bar](input){};` or whatever way of positioning the node. You don't need the `aux` coordinate or `local bounding box`. And a second thing about fitting nodes, it's better to use `label=center:xxxxxxx` to place the text instead of `{}`.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you so much! I didn't know this.